# Получение фонового изображения, Android

Tags: android, bitmap

Есть приложение, в котором используется тема **Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.FullScreen**, что позволяет реализовать в качестве фона изображение рабочего стола. Появилась необходимость сделать этот фон размытым. Флаг **FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND** для **WindowManager** не подходит, поэтому надумал реализовать программное получение фонового изображения, его размытие и последующую установку на фон.

Для этого опробовал два способа. Первый:

```
WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
Drawable drawable = wm.getFastDrawable();
```

Второй:

```
View v1 = ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container)).getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
```

В первом случае использую **WallpaperManager** для получения фонового изображения рабочего стола. Метод не подходит, т.к. в ответ приходит Bitmap, содержащий все изображение, установленное на обои. Т.е. без обрезки. Во втором случае делаю скриншот экрана приложения. Метод вызываю до установки элементов на Layout, т.е. в тот момент, когда на экране виден только слегка затемненный фон рабочего стола (благодаря теме). Но метод не срабатывает, третья строка возвращает null, хотя и пробовал менять тему. После же компановки экрана метод работает.

Что подскажите, как заставить приложение работать как нужно?

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки о том, что не подходит. В этой теме подходит, но с depricated warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372404/alternative-to-flag-blur-behind-in-android ?

Comment: @php5 Как понял там рекомендуют использовать затемнение, реализуемое различными способами. Но мне нужно размытие. Ошибку данный флаг никакую не выдает и эффекта от него никакого. На сайте android developer сказано, что данный флаг не работает с API версии 14.

Answer (score 2):

## Как получить изображение фона (точнее любой View, в нашем случае rootView)?

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.layout(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
    view.draw(c);
    return bitamp;
}
```

## Теперь надо применить Blur к Bitmap (полученному выше)?

Для начала инициализируем константы, используемые при создании Blur.

```
private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.5f; // кроп-фактор для исходного изображения
private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 6.0f;  // радиус пятна размытия в диапазоне 0 < BLUR_RADIUS <= 25
```

Так как мы используем `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` из [v8 support library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur.html), необходимо будет включить поддержку в `gradle` файле.

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    renderscriptTargetApi *your target api*
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
  }
  ...
}
```

Теперь сам код для получения Bitmap с эффектом blur, который использует клвссы `RenderScript` и `ScriptIntrinsicBlur`:

```
public static Bitmap blur(Context ctx, Bitmap image) {
        int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
        int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

        Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(ctx);
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

        return outputBitmap;
    }
```

## Как связать все вышеописанное?

Добавляем описанный ниже код в метод `onCreateView()` и наслаждаемся результатом.

```
final Activity activity = getActivity();
final View content = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
if (content.getWidth() > 0) {
    Bitmap image = blur(content.getContext(),getBitmapFromView(content));
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), image));
} else {
    content.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Bitmap image = blur(content.getContext(),getBitmapFromView(content));
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), image));
        }
    });
}
```